# awk/join ? How do I print field from column based on match between two files

Tags: join, awk, sed

I have three files I'd like to join into one, semicolon delimited (note multiple occurences in file 1 of first row value possible)

File 1:

```
1;FOO;BAR;NU
1;V;V;E
2;F;B;N
3;FOO;NU;BAR
```

File 2:

```
1;YES
2;NO
3;YES
```

File 3:

```
1;NO
2;NO
3;YES
```

Desired outcome: (file1 $0, file2 $2, file3 $2)

```
1;FOO;BAR;NU;YES;NO
1;V;V;E;YES;NO
2;F;B;N;NO;NO
3;FOO;NU;BAR;YES;YES
```

I cant get my head around how this can be done... so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU join):

```
join -t\; file1 file2 | join -t\; - file3
```

Join file1 and file2 first using `;` as the field delimiter and pipe the result to a second invocation of join using stdin and file3 and the same delimiter.

Comment: Thank you !
I initially had an issue with an unwanted character in file1 (windows residue), but after fixing that it worked perfectly fine, I had lured myself into additional commands for join, without realizing that it could do a 1 to many join byitself.

Comment: @LeifHvitved whenever you have a big job to do, recursion usually shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` you may do this:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
ARGIND == 1 {
   ++fr[$1]
   map[$1][fr[$1]] = $0
   next
}
$1 in fr {
   for (i in map[$1])
      map[$1][i] = map[$1][i] OFS $2
}
END {
   for (i in map)
      for (j in map[i])
         print map[i][j]
}' file1 file2 file3
```

```
1;FOO;BAR;NU;YES;NO
1;V;V;E;YES;NO
2;F;B;N;NO;NO
3;FOO;NU;BAR;YES;YES
```